# ASP.NET Core server side Identity in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, asp.net-core-identity

What's the correct way to use server side ASP.NET Core Identity in a Teams Web App?
I have an ASP.NET Core application (Razor Pages) with a classic Cookie Authentication.
I need to show that application in a Teams Tab.

I managed to show the WebApp in the Teams Tab (the anonymous pages), but when the user access the protected pages, the page redirect to Microsoft Login do not work.

The samples in Microsoft Docs show how to use client side OAuth2 authentication (with `MicrosoftTeams.js`) but what's the correct way to authenticate the user server side?

Comment: Common redirect process Mean? how you are redirecting? OAuth 2.0 is an open standard for authentication and authorization used by Azure Active Directory (AAD) and many other identity providers.Please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-flow-tab) for more info. Also check this [sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/tab-channel-group-config-page-auth/csharp).

Comment: I mean that Azure AD Authentication in a classic ASP.NET Core application use
`services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))`. When user access an `[Authorize]` Page ASP.NET Core do a redirect to Microsoft Login. That redirect do not works in Teams.

Comment: Could you please check the [Web-based authentication flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/authentication#web-based-authentication-flow). try if that helps.

Comment: Every sample uses client side authentication and API calls with OAuth 2 passing Access Token. I would to use server side ASP.NET Core Razor Pages that generates pages and use Cookie for authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently teams does not support complete server side authentication. Teams uses the Microsoft libraries which calls client. You can get the Auth token using Microsoft libraries and do the further process on server side authentication. Teams support client side Authentication,This is by design.